# How to use Spring DI in class constructed by another framework (using new)?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, apache-axis

I am doing some work on a legacy SOAP app which uses `Axis2`. I would like to introduce some basic `Spring` injection. The app has an Axis2 service config that specifies:

```
<ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
    <ramp:timestampTTL>300</ramp:timestampTTL>  
    <ramp:timestampMaxSkew>300</ramp:timestampMaxSkew>
    <ramp:user>service</ramp:user>
    <ramp:encryptionUser>useReqSigCert</ramp:encryptionUser>
    <ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
        com.myapp.SomeCallbackHandler
    </ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
```

Which probably means that Axis2 instantiates `SomeCallbackHandler` using reflection (and ultimately `new`, which clashes with the way Spring works) and in that class I would like to inject a bean which is loaded via `ContextLoaderListener`:

```
@Component
public class SomeCallbackHandler implements CallbackHandler {

    @Autowired
    private InjectedConfigClass myConfig;
```

Since the scope of my refactoring is limited and I can't bypass the use of Axis2, is there any way I can still use a Spring injected bean in a callback class that is defined to Axis2 in its XML config?

Comment: Use a configuration.

Comment: As in `@Configuration` ?

Comment: yes that's the one

Comment: i couldn't get it to work

Comment: keep trying....