# Using static method to overcome context inaccessibilty

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, static-methods

I am doing some work on a legacy SOAP app which uses `Axis2`. I would like to introduce some basic `Spring` `injection`. The app has an Axis2 service config that specifies:

```
<ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
    <ramp:timestampTTL>300</ramp:timestampTTL>  
    <ramp:timestampMaxSkew>300</ramp:timestampMaxSkew>
    <ramp:user>service</ramp:user>
    <ramp:encryptionUser>useReqSigCert</ramp:encryptionUser>
    <ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
        com.myapp.SomeCallbackHandler
    </ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
```

Axis2 instantiates *SomeCallbackHandler* using reflection (and ultimately new, which clashes with the way Spring works) and in that class I would like to inject a bean which is loaded via `ContextLoaderListener`. I experimented with [`axis2-spring`](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/spring.html) and, while there seems to be a way to bridge the two and inject Spring context beans into an Axis2 service class, the problem is that SomeCallbackHandler is not a service. So I could not find a proper way to link it with the Spring context.

The way I worked around is I created a wrapper class that contains the variable I want to inject and makes it available statically:

```
public class ContextCarrier {

    //I get vomit in my throat when I have to use static
    private static MyConfig config;

    public void setConfig(MyConfig _config) {
        config = _config;
    }

    //I really hate this but it works
    public static MyConfig getConfig() {
        return config;
    }
}
```

In my `context.xml`:

```
<bean id="hackBean" class="my.app.ContextCarrier">
    <property name="config" ref="serverConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="serverConfig" class="my.app.MyConfig">
    <property name="connection" ref="cxnBean" />
</bean>
```

SomeCallbackHandler (Apache Rampart's passwordCallbackClass implementation):

```
public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException,
            UnsupportedCallbackException {

            ...
            MyConfig myConfig = ContextCarrier.getConfig();
            ...
```

My question is, just how bad is this hack of overcoming inaccessibility to Spring context via static methods? I would really like to never have to use static methods anywhere except for maybe constants and factories because they defy the purpose of object orientation.

<sub>**RELATED:**</sub>

- [How to inject Spring bean in Apache Rampart passwordCallbackClass in Axis2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900351/how-to-inject-spring-bean-in-apache-rampart-passwordcallbackclass-in-axis2)
- [How to use Spring DI in class constructed by another framework (using new)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881260/how-to-use-spring-di-in-class-constructed-by-another-framework-using-new)

Comment: It does look ugly but the practical question is: can you unit test your handler? And the answer is that with the exception of the static methods themselves, you can. Specifically any mocks created for `my.app.MyConfig`  in the Spring context will be passed on to your callback handler. So unless you can get Axis to cooperate with Spring (and I wish you good luck with that :)), this is probably the least worst solution.

Comment: "least worst"  -- I like that